# SonarQube: is it possible to change the time zone in the JVM parameters?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube-ops

I have a machine that runs several different servers and it's in a specific time zone in Central Europe.

I need to run SonarQube (4.5.7) in UTC time.

I uncommented the following line in `web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb` and restarted SonarQube but the server still shows the original time zone on the System Info page.

`config.time_zone = 'UTC'`

Should that be enough to change the time zone in SonarQube? Because that didn't really work.

Is there a way I can pass the `user.timezone` property to the JVM by editing the `wrapper.conf` file? Looks like it could work but it doesn't look like I'm supposed to touch that file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internal files, including web/**/*, must not be touched.

To change JVM timezone, you should edit conf/sonar.properties and add the value `-Duser.timezone=Europe/Sofia` to properties `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts`, `sonar.ce.javaAdditionalOpts` and `sonar.search.javaAdditionalOpts`.